# Please guide me what is wrong with this query in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have two tables users and assets and foreign key is **user_id**. I want users detail and count of each user's asset So, I wrote query as below but not getting records. Please help me.

```
$users = $this->select()
             ->from(array('u' => 'users'),
                    array('firstname'))
             ->joinLeft(array('a' => 'assets'),
                    'u.id = a.user_id',
                    array('asset_per_user' => 'COUNT(a.id)'))
             ->group('u.id');
```

Comment: Do you call "$result = $this->fetchAll($users);" later on? And if yes, do you get any error message there?

Comment: Yes, but Getting this type of error 'Select query cannot join with another table '.

Comment: In this case regilero gave the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 'Select query cannot join with another table '

That mean `$this` is quite certainly a **Zend_Db_Table** in your example. By default select taken from a Zend_Db_Table cannot perform joins (as they are used for Active Record operation by default).

Add:

```
$users->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

And this merror essage will disappears. I've not checked the SQL query yet, it's maybe right.

Answer (score 0):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.table.html

See Example #28 "Removing the integrity check on Zend_Db_Table_Select to allow JOINed rows"

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same problem. this is because you are connecting with a database table that is not related to the specific table. So, we need to turn off the integrity test. you can view the detail solution [here](http://newdailyblog.blogspot.com/2012/07/error-select-query-cannot-join-with.html).

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.